# How to completely remove Folx on Mac OS X?

Tags: software, utilities, file-transfer, macos

I installed Folx download manager on my MacBook Pro. I didn't like it, so I removed it from the Applications folder. I also searched for its dependent files in `/Library/Preferences`, but I found nothing related to Folx.

Now, when I try to download files, it tries to download using Folx—but Folx doesn't work. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Probably it is still integrated with your browser. What browser are you using?

Comment: Try following the [official uninstallation instructions](http://wiki.eltima.com/user-guides/downloader-macos/uninstall.html).

Comment: @anyone can this be done using the command line on mac?

Comment: Try taking a look at the answers to [Don't want Folx become my default downloader](http://superuser.com/questions/58346/dont-want-folx-become-my-default-downloader) (on Super User) and see if one of them helps.

Answer (score 2):

## For prior version than Folx 4

Go Download the Folx.dmg from their website, and open it. In the dmg image, there will be a package file called **uninstaller**. Run that.

It is only for prior versions than Folx 4, as said by [Eltima Software](https://www.eltima.com/wiki/user-guides/downloader-macos/uninstall-folx.html). For Folx 4 or newer, it is mentionned on [their website](https://www.eltima.com/wiki/user-guides/uninstall-mac.html) that it is enough to remove Folx.app to permanently remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I use 10.8.5 and here how it is to remove folx completely

1. launch folx
2. In menubar -  click help>uninstall
3. you will get below! window
4. select all options
5. Uninstall

[image: folx download manager complete uninstall]

Comment: The `Help > Uninstall` menu item does not exist in Folx 5.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Firefox you should also unistall Folx plugin (Tools->Add-ons->Plugins->Folx Downloader Netscape plug-in -> disable)

Answer (score 0):

To remove Folx you are to use its uninstaller.

Answer (score 0):

the uninstaller did not work for me at all. I had to remove many pieces from the file system. I think the key was to remove the app from ~user/Library/ScriptingAdditions!

Answer (score -1):

Download official uninstaller below: (Thanks Gilles for the comment)

[Folx - Uninstall Folx](http://wiki.eltima.com/user-guides/downloader-macos/uninstall.html)

Answer (score -3):

Open the Applications folder in Finder, select the app and drag it to Trash (located at the end of Dock). Then choose Finder → Empty Trash. When you empty the trash, the app is permanently removed from your Mac.

Comment: The OP did this but still runs into problems.

Comment: It's written here https://wiki.eltima.com/user-guides/uninstall-mac.html man!

Comment: I'm aware of that, so is the OP who "removed it from the Applications folder". Still "when I try to download files, it tries to download using Folx—but Folx doesn't work" so it seems as if removing just the application isn't enough to uninstall it.